# CQ5 Java QueryBuilder API

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have seen in adobe API documentation QueryBuilder Service which can be called by URLs for many query options, this returns JSON based responses. Very well. I wan to use this in java API. I have found some examples and tried in eclipse but some thing i dont know that how to get the Service "sling" as in given code below: OR in other words how to make a QueryBuilder Java object.

Any specific JAR i needed or i need to install Apache SLING on my PC i am not sure any one who can share this will be helpful as i am new to CQ5 and has no idea.

The example code is as below:

```
        Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository(SERVER);
        SimpleCredentials credentials = new SimpleCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        Session session = repository.login(credentials);
        System.out.println("got session: " + session);

        /*HERE SLING IS THE PROBLEM HOW TO GET SLING */  
        QueryBuilder qbuilder = sling.getService(QueryBuilder.class);
        String fulltextSearchTerm = "Geometrixx";

        // create query description as hash map (simplest way, same as form
        // post)
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // create query description as hash map (simplest way, same as form
        // post)
        map.put("path", "/content");
        map.put("type", "cq:Page");
        map.put("group.p.or", "true"); // combine this group with OR
        map.put("group.1_fulltext", fulltextSearchTerm);
        map.put("group.1_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content");
        map.put("group.2_fulltext", fulltextSearchTerm);
        map.put("group.2_fulltext.relPath", "jcr:content/@cq:tags");

        // can be done in map or with Query methods
        map.put("p.offset", "0"); // same as query.setStart(0) below
        map.put("p.limit", "20"); // same as query.setHitsPerPage(20) below

        Query query = qbuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
        query.setStart(0);
        query.setHitsPerPage(20);

        SearchResult result = query.getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in a Java class rather than a JSP, you can use `@Reference` annotation to do a look-up of a given service — this will find a matching service registered by OSGi and return an implementation of it to you.

From the [Felix SCR documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#reference):

> The @Reference annotation defines references to other services made
>   available to the component by the Service Component Runtime.

Your code then becomes simply:

```
@Reference
QueryBuilder qbuilder;
```

Comment: thanks for answer but still QueryBuilder is null at runtime. I have a simple class with main() method. And I have added Flix Annotation Jar in build path. CQ5 server is locally running.

Comment: @zaxeer Are you running this code when deployed into your CQ instance, or as stand-alone class? You won't be able to use `getService` or `@Reference` without being in an OSGi container — it's Felix that's providing the service in each case.

Comment: I am running code as standalone java application, my java application parse the JCR tree, but new requirement was to search in contents.

Comment: Going by the [JavaDoc](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/QueryBuilder.html), the QueryBuilder doesn't expose a public constructor & it mentions "*All examples assume that `queryBuilder` is available as an OSGi SCR reference.*". — You could  possibly use reflection to create an instance, though I'd say you're definitely looking at an unsupported scenario if using it outside of CQ.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using adobe cq osgi magic...Add a private field in your class to hold the ComponentContext.

```
private ComponentContext context;
```

Implement the activate method:

```
protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then you can use this context to get the queryBuilder:

```
ServiceReference queryBuilderReference = context.getBundleContext().getServiceReference(QueryBuilder.class.getName());
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = (QueryBuilder) context.getBundleContext().getService(queryBuilderReference);
```

Comment: Thanks @Calahad. I tried many things but only your solution only worked :)